# Как создать триггер в mysql, который будет добавлять записи в связанную таблицу?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

**SELECT * FROM items_table;**

```
+---------+-----------+
| item_id | item_name |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 | Item#1    |
|       2 | Item#2    |
+---------+-----------+
```

**SELECT * FROM sites_table;**

```
+---------+-----------+
| site_id | site_name |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 | Site#1    |
|       5 | Site#2    |
+---------+-----------+
```

**SELECT * FROM links_table;**

```
+---------+--------+---------+---------+
| link_id | url    | item_id | site_id |
+---------+--------+---------+---------+
|       2 | Link#1 |       1 |       1 |
|       3 | Link#3 |       1 |       5 |
|       4 | Link#4 |       2 |       5 |
|       5 | Link#2 |       2 |       1 |
+---------+--------+---------+---------+
```

Мне требуется триггер, который сработает на событие новой записи в sites_table. Задача триггера вставить в links_table недостающие записи.

**Как я представляю триггер:**

1. Перебирает items_table
2. На каждой итерации он ищет в links_table запись, где item_id = item_id текущего элемента итерации items_table и site_id = site_id созданной записи в sites_table.
3. Если нет, то добавляет в links_table запись, где item_id равен item_id из текущего элемента итерации items_table и site_id из созданной записи в sites_table.

То есть, при создании новой записи в sites_table, должны создаваться записи в links_table по строкам из items_table.

**item_id, site_id, link_id являются внешними ключами.**

**Колонка url в sites_table** по умолчанию не имеет значения и в задаче не требуется. Я ее указал для облегчения понимания.

Comment: А данные для колонки URL где он возьмет ? Она однозначно вычисляема на основании link_id ? Если так - то эта колонка вам вообще не нужна, ибо ее всегда можно вычислить. У вас в этой таблице хранятся связи гарантированно _все_ со _всеми_ двух таблиц. Но тогда выходит, что эта таблица существует только ради вычисления URL от некого числа, номера связи. Тогда возникает вопрос, а нужна ли вообще эта таблица, если link_id при желании можно посчитать по какой нибудь формуле исходя из site_id и item_id

Comment: И по вашему триггеру я не понял, зачем он должен искать записи в links_table с требуемым site_id, если этот site_id только что создан и в links _не может быть записей_ с таким site_id. Тогда задача сводится к `insert into links_table(item_id,site_id) select item_id,NEW.site_id from items_table;` (NEW - так в триггерах mysql обозначается новая запись и ее колонки)

Comment: Понятно что есть желание создать триггер. Что-то пробовали уже сделать? Что конкретно не получается?

Comment: @Mike, спасибо большое. Ваш запрос идеально подошел. Оформите ваш последний комментарий в ответ, пожалуйста. Вы порекомендуете что-нибудь для изучения sql?

Comment: @Steve даже не знаю что читать, как то ооочень давно работаю с ним,  и все знания скорее на опыте основаны, даже не припомню что читал. отовсюду понемногу видимо. И все таки желание вставить все записи сразу - немного странно. Обычно вставляют записи по мере необходимости. А отсутствие каких либо записей в таблице на запросы сказываться не должно, ибо существует `LEFT JOIN` позволяющий получать записи из связанных таблиц вне зависимости от наличия записей в одной из них. С дугой стороны ситуации конечно разные бывают ...

Comment: @Mike, возможно у меня неправильная архитектура приложения. Это первое приложение, где я не использую готовые решения для работы с БД. Я придерживаюсь малой связанности, но видимо мое решение можно потом доработать. Я выбрал это решение взамен условию LINK ? UPDATE : INSERT в самом коде приложения.

Comment: @Steve Собственно я предлагаю почитать в интернете про `left join`, если его еще не знаете, чуть чуть поэкспериментировать ... Тогда может и новые идеи для архитектуры появятся...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо создать триггер на событие insert в таблицу sites_table, который будет выполнять единственный SQL запрос:

```
insert into links_table(item_id,site_id)
select item_id,NEW.site_id
  from items_table;
```

Он возьмет все существующие item_id и добавит их в links с второй колонкой - id site из создаваемой записи в sites. Искать существующие записи в links смысла не имеет, ибо записей с только что созданным site_id там быть не может.

Comment: а еще можно такой же запрос, если не сложно, на триггер, который срабатывает при добавлении записи в items_table. Он должен смотреть на sites_table.

Comment: Ну собственно в этом все item на site заменить и наоборот. `insert into links_table(item_id,site_id) select NEW.item_id,site_id
  from sites_table;`

Comment: спасибо. Работает.